# Why the value form <input> is copied to all another inputs?

Tags: html, angular

this is part of my code:

```
<input style="width:100px;" #quantity name="vehicle{{i}}_quantity"
class="options-input" [(ngModel)]="detail.quantity" type="number" required [ngClass]="{ 'error-bottom-border': quantity.value.length==0}" placeholder="0" min="0" [disabled]="viewMode">
```

When I put a value to one of the inputs all others get the same value. I dont't want this. I tried to add:

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

But still nothing. Every input has uniqe name.
I hope that is a simple case.

**ALL CODE**

http://pasted.co/85f3a46b

Comment: What other inputs? Show more of your code, please.

Comment: Are you using dummy data which you create by your own? If so, please share this part of the code.

Comment: Please show in the question the relevant markup for the `ngFor` loop (at least the declaration of the loop), and the code/markup where `detail` is defined.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, so do you have any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

did you use same ngModel for all the input? if yes that's the problem .Ngmodel is used to bind data to the input .

Comment: I have p-dataTable (PrimeNG) and I generate dynamically rows with inputs using *ngFor